# String list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a string list including some words. For example, I have

```
words={cut, was, saw, clear, sharp, keen, tree, these};
```

I want to write a code that changes the first letter of each word to the capital letter. I mean I want to have the result as

```
{Cut, Was, Saw, Clear, Sharp, Keen, Tree, These};
```

How can I figure it out?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by 'string list', there are no strings in `words`. Also, have you tried searching documentation for string related functions that could help you?

Comment: Strings go between `"` quotes in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input and the desired output are lists of `String`s:

```
strings = {"cut", "was", "saw", "clear", "sharp", "keen", "tree", "these"};

GeneralUtilities`ToTitleCase[strings]
```

> {"Cut", "Was", "Saw", "Clear", "Sharp", "Keen", "Tree", "These"}

Alternatively, you can use [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html):

```
StringReplace[strings, WordBoundary ~~ a_ :> ToUpperCase[a]]
```

> {"Cut", "Was", "Saw", "Clear", "Sharp", "Keen", "Tree", "These"}

If the input and desired output are lists of `Symbol`s:

```
words = {cut, was, saw, clear, sharp, keen, tree, these};

Symbol /@ GeneralUtilities`ToTitleCase[ToString /@ words]
```

> {Cut, Was, Saw, Clear, Sharp, Keen, Tree, These}

Answer (score 7):

Could also use [`Capitalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Capitalize):

```
Capitalize[{"cut", "was", "saw", "clear", "sharp", "keen", "tree", "these"}]
```

> {"Cut", "Was", "Saw", "Clear", "Sharp", "Keen", "Tree", "These"}